# How can you find all HTML hyper link tags in a string and replace them with their href value?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I'd like to take a string of text and find all of the hyper link tags, grab their href value, and replace the entire hyper link tag with the value of the href attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many possibilities. E.g. by using the [DOM extension](http://docs.php.net/dom), [DOMDocument::loadhtml()](http://docs.php.net/domdocument.loadhtml) and [XPath](http://docs.php.net/class.domdxpath) (though getElementsbyTagName() would suffice in this case).

```
<?php
$string = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
  <p>
    mary had a <a href="little">greedy</a> lamb
    whose fleece was <a href="white">cold</a> as snow
  </p>
</body></html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml($string);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query('//a') as $a ) {
  $tn = $doc->createTextNode($a->getAttribute('href'));
  $a->parentNode->replaceChild($tn, $a);
}

echo $doc->savehtml();
```

prints

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>...</title></head>
<body><p>
    mary had a little lamb
    whose fleece was white as snow
  </p></body>
</html>
```

Comment: @OregonGhost - Doing it with regex would be probably not the best idea anyway... +1 from me as well

Comment: @VolkerK this worked like a charm. I had no idea this kind of alternative existed and it seems much simpler than using regex.

@OregonGhost & @Buggabill Why is regex not a preferred method? Is it just over kill or over complication some times?

Thank you again for the help! :)

Comment: @hsatterwhite: see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html Regular expressions may be _part_ of the parser but regular expressions alone can't do the job (for arbitrary html)

Comment: Wow, that's an excellent read! I'd up vote, but I'm too new. ;)

Comment: Having said that if you can make certain assumptions about the string (the structure and the characters it can contain) it might be possible to use regular expressions. And Jeriko has a point in saying "at least regex won't break if the HTML isn't well-formed". Take a close look at the output of my example. Even in this case the underlying libxml made some small changes (where to use linebreaks in this case). The output is "only" equivalent. But in general you will (and should) get raised eye-browses when you use regular expressions to parse html.

Comment: Yea, I noticed Jeriko's comment and I think your suggested method will work fine since I am using a WYSIWYG editor that is creating relatively good markup for these hyper links. I'm going to have to read more in to your solution considering I've never even heard of it. Is it painfully obvious that I'm a bit of a novice? ;)

Comment: You can use a HTML parser like BeautifulSoup, which will also not break if the HTML isn't well-formed. However, to learn why regex (in general) is not a good idea for parsing HTML, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454